# How can I achieve 8-bit graphics effect using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I achieve 8-bit graphics effect using Silverlight?

I want to make retro game for WP7 using Silverlight.

Should I use canvas and rectangle for this?

Comment: You may want to use the XNA development path for a game like this.

Comment: I don't know XNA, really. And I just want to make retro game menu and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for this. Since you are developing a game, you will have to create a custom layer engine that will be able to place colored rectangles in different zones of the screen, therefore achieving the desired effect.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but what about putting a single pixel? Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible through WriteableBitmap, but you would have to manually alter the pixels and for that you should now the pixel ID. On a sidenote, you will be working with ARGB color indicators.